# Sending keyboard events using a service in windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I understand that it is not normally possible to send keyboard events using a windows service because it does not have access to a window if I'm not mistaken. Could someone please suggest a possible workaround for this to enable a service to send keyboard events to a window. Any help would be appreciated and would be instrumental in my work.

Thank you very much

Comment: Not directly from C#... You could write an input driver, or use something that already has calling that from your service. Take a look at https://www.autohotkey.com/ etc. they have source code available (but its in C++)

Comment: Does the service need to send input to a specific window, or does it just need emulate normal keyboard presses (which go to the active window)? And is the service running under the user account that is hosting the window, or is it running under a system account?

Comment: It needs to emulate normal keyboard presses as you said and it will run under a system account. The previous comment about writing an input driver sounds very promising but honestly, I do not know how to go about doing that

Comment: I usually use p/invoke when I need to emulate input, specifically `SendInput`. But I don't think that works from a service. Services are generally designed not to be able to interact directly with a user's desktop- and there are good security concerns behind that. Usually there is a separate "tray application" running on the user's login the facilitates communication with the service.

Comment: Yes I have tried using SendInput. Visual Studio wont even let me compile. It cant be used from there. Okay new question, it may be stupid but can a system tray application start without having logged in to an account. In other words. Right after bootup

Comment: I know something like this is possible, but I couldn't tell you how. TeamViewer has a feature where, if you reboot the computer while someone is connected remotely, the remote session automatically reconnects *before* you're even logged back in to the computer. It shows you the lock screen and lets you log in yourself. So it's definitely possible to start a program that interacts with the desktop before anyone has even logged in... somehow.